# undefined reference to constructor using templates c++

Tags: c++, templates

I've built a LinkedList with template but compiling returns undefined reference to the constructor and destructor and will not compile

From driver:

```
LinkedList<int> myList;
```

From .cpp

```
template <class itemType>
LinkedList<itemType>::LinkedList()

{
    size = 0;
    head = NULL;
}
```

driver.cpp:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `LinkedList<int>::LinkedList()'
driver.cpp:(.text+0x31): undefined reference to`LinkedList::~LinkedList()'

Comment: What is the type of `size` and `head`?

Comment: Could you post the types of the other variables?

Comment: The implementations of any *class template* or *function template* is supposed to be visible to the compiler at point of instatiation, however, if it's not visible at point of instatiation, then it should have been explicitly instatiated in another translation unit that you link with, else you'll get this error. See [Why can templates only be implemented in header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: Edit.. Ended up deleting #include the .h and subbed #include the cpp and it worked??